# HTML form: Scandinavian characters in userID and password

Tags: forms

How to make HTML form accept scandinavian characters in passwords and userIDs? For example, I just changed my password to something that has the letter Å in it. Upon sending the form, it gives the error message that the password is wrong. Is there a way in the form tag to handle this? I tried the enctype, but didn't help.

Comment: HTML form provide no means of checking passwords, the error is being provided by your backend. which platform/framework are you using? I'm assuming either PhP or asp but I'd prefer to be sure...

Comment: By putting this setting 'accept-charset="ISO-8859-1' in the form tag, I managed to handle that problem, but then the other problem is that Internet Exploter doesn't support that, while works in other browsers. The form action is handled by an application that is coded in C.

Comment: This did the IE trick as well: onsubmit="document.charset = 'ISO-8859-1'.